# Netty SslHandler sends no close_notify

Tags: netty

Our netty sever with SSLHandler does not respond to close_notify and FIN from peer. Requirement is netty SslHandler should send close_notify as per RFC here. We are using Netty-4.1.17 with Opensslengine.

```
7.2.1.  Closure Alerts [[https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.2.1]]
   The client and the server must share knowledge that the connection is 
   ending in order to avoid a truncation attack. 
   [...] 
   Unless some other fatal alert has been transmitted, each party is 
   required to send a close_notify alert before closing the write side 
   of the connection.  The other party MUST respond with a close_notify 
   alert of its own and close down the connection immediately, 
   discarding any pending writes.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this was fixed in later netty releases. Please upgrade to latest version

Comment: i tested with version 4.1.21 Final with stanard JDK 1.8.u121 SSLEngine, i can see my client (jmeter) in all 1000 requests was sending close_notify Alert but Netty-Server was not responding with close_notify.

Comment: see [wireshark capture](https://ufile.io/s8r0o)  Use the following wireshark filter tcp.port eq 8443 and ssl.record.length > 2 and ssl.record.content_type == 21    . Then follow SSL Stream. I think Netty is swallowing the close_notify alert sent by SSLEngine.